# Is there a gtest equivalent for fixture-level setup/teardown?

Tags: c++, testing, googletest

So, I know there's "literally" fixtures for gtest, but the constructor/destructor and setup/teardown functions will execute *after each test* rather than *after the entire set of tests in the fixture*.

I can think of ways of hacking around this, but is there some built-in support that I'm not finding?

Answer (score 15):

You can define static methods `SetUpTestSuite` and `TearDownTestSuite` in your test fixture class:

```
struct MyTest: ::testing::Test {
    static void SetUpTestSuite() {
        
    }

    static void TearDownTestSuite() {
        
    }
};
```

More information on that is in the [Googletest wiki](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#sharing-resources-between-tests-in-the-same-test-suite).

Be careful about the spelling of these static method names.

Comment: Be careful about correct spelling. The methods are `SetUpTestCase` and `TearDownTestCase`, with leading capitals and the `U` in `Up` is capitalized too.

Comment: While your answer works, the linked wiki page has no additional information on those methods and a quick search in the repository unveils that they are [deprecated](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/8697709e0308af4cd5b09dc108480804e5447cf0/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h#L430).

Comment: Yes, they have been renamed in the library to match the common nomenclature. I've edit the answer to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 5):

Google Test supports set-up and tear-down on test (test method) level, suite (class) level and also on **program level**. The later is the one you seam to look for:

https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#global-set-up-and-tear-down describes how you can derive and register you own *environment-fixture* class implementing set-up and tear-down methods, which are called only once during the execution of your test runner.

In short you can do something similar to that:

```
class SetupEnvironment : public ::testing::Environment
{
public:
  virtual ~SetupEnvironment();
  void SetUp() override { ... }
  void TearDown() override { ... }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  testing::AddGlobalTestEnvironment(new SetupEnvironment());
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```